# Anything wrong with this 'proof'?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

**Problem.**
Show that $e^{-x}$ and $\sin(x)$ intersect infinitely many times.

**Solution.**

$\lim_{x \to o} e^{-x} = e^0 = 1$

$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-x} = 0$

This shows that as $e^{-x}$ goes from 0 to infinity, its range approaches 0. But this is not enough to show that they intersect infinitely many times. We must show that the range of $e^{-x}$ is contained between $1$ and $-1$ from 0 to infinity (the range of $\sin(x)$). We can do this by looking for extremas on $e^{-x}$.

$$\frac{d}{dx} e^{-x} = -e^{-x}$$
$$-e^{-x} = 0 \Rightarrow \text{False!}$$

We can therefore conclude that as $e^{-x}$ is contained within the range of $\sin(x)$ from $0$ to $\infty$, they must intersect infinitely many times.

---

My professor said that my proof was, and I quote: "An idea that could use more work" and only gave me 15% out of 25% for the problem on the test. He obviously wanted us to use the mean-value theorem, but as he didn't require it on the question, I thought I'd show it this way...Is there anything wrong with my proof and does it really need more work??

Comment: You need to add some more details to the proof of $e^{-x}$ being contained between $-1$ and $1$. Then you say "they must intersect infinitely many times", without bothering to explain why. It may be obvious to you, but this requires a proof.

Comment: I mean to show with my derivative test that the function is ever-decreasing from 1 to 0.

Answer (score 1):

The proof does need more work. You have shown there are no local extremes of $e^{-x}$ on $[0,\infty)$, however your conclusion, that therefore $e^{-x}$ is contained, is a total non sequitor.

The fact that a function does not have extremas has nothing at all to do with the fact that it is contained. As an example, take $f(x) = x$, which also has a nonzero derivative.

Even upon proving that, you then say that because the range of $e^{-x}$ is contained in the range of $\sin x$, this means that there are infinitely many intersections, however if you take the function $\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}$, this function has a range which is contained in the range of $e^{-x}$, but the functions **never** intersect.

Comment: What if I had added that $-e^{-0.99}<0$ and therefore the slope is ever decreasing from 1 to 0 as x goes from 0 to infinity. As sin(x) is a periodic function with the range [1,-1] then my proof holds..?

Comment: The slope is ever decreasing only if all values of the derivative are negative, not just one.

Also, as for the periodic $\sin x$, yes, the function is periodic. And yes, that is why there are an infinite number of intersections. But the point is that you have to show WHY this is so. You cannot just say "because it is periodic". You have to prove each statement you use.

Comment: If the slope is negative slightly below 0 and there is no extrema, then it must be negative all the way...?

Comment: Or you can just say that $-e^{-x}$ is a negative value for all $x$. But you still havent adressed the other problem in your proof.

Comment: So we agree that if slightly edited, my proof shows that $e^{-x}$ is contained within the range of $\sin(x)$. But you say that I must prove that they intersect...Isn't it enough to note that as $\sin(x)$ is periodic on the interval $[0,\infty[$ then they must intersect infinitely many times?

Comment: No. That is exactly what you must prove, not just say it's obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is not complete as was noted by the others.

A correct solution would be:

Set $f(x)=\sin(x)-e^{-x}$. $f$ is continuous.

Let $k\ge 0$ be an integer. Then $f(\pi/2+2\pi k)=1-e^{-(\pi/2+2\pi k)}>0$ and $f(3\pi/2+2\pi k)=-1-e^{-(3\pi/2+2\pi k)}<-1$.

By the intermediate value theorem, $f$ has a zero in every interval $(\pi/2+2\pi k,3\pi/2+2\pi k)$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$. That is, there are infinitely many zeros of $f$, i.e. infinitely many solutions of $\sin(x)=e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 0):

We know the following basic facts.

1) Because of periodicity $f(x) = \sin x$ takes the values $0$ and $1$ infinitely many times at regular intervals. This means that given any number $N > 0$ there are infinitely many values of $x$ for which $x > N$ and $\sin x = 0$. And another set of infinitely many values of $x$ exist such that $x > N$ and $\sin x = 1$.

2) $\lim_{x \to \infty}e^{-x} = 0$. Note that $e^{-x} > 0$ for all $x$ and hence this limit implies that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a number $N > 0$ such that $0 < e^{-x} < \epsilon$ for all $x > N$. Taking $\epsilon = 1$ we see that there is an $N > 0$ such that $0 < e^{-x} < 1$ for all $x > N$.

Considering the above statements we see that for $x > N$, $e^{-x}$ lies between the bounds $0$ and $1$ (and never attains these bounds) and $f(x) = \sin x$ attains both these values $0, 1$ infinitely many times. It clearly follows by intermediate value theorem that $f(x) = \sin x$ intersects $e^{-x}$ infinitely many times. We don't need to actually figure out the points where $f(x) = \sin x$ takes the values $0, 1$. We just need to know that infinitely many such values exist.